# Why does a GeoFire query sometimes use data from a previous load?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

So sometimes someone in *entered the search radius* is from before, ie someone who was in search radius, but based on the current data in the database is not in the radius. Other times, someone who wasn't in the search radius before but now is, doesn't get printed.

This only happens once each time, ie if I load the app for the second time after the erroneous inclusion or exclusion, the correct array prints.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    latestLocation = ["latitude" : locValue.latitude, "longitude" : locValue.longitude]
    let lat = locValue.latitude
    let lon = locValue.longitude
    dict = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    print("dict", dict)

    if let locationDictionary = latestLocation {
        databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates").setValue(locationDictionary)
        let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("Loc")
        let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
        print(CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon),"GGG")
        geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon), forKey: uid)
    }

    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }

Override func ViewdidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("Loc")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
    geoFire.getLocationForKey(uid) { (location, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("An error occurred getting the location for \"Coordinates\": \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        } else if (location != nil) {
            print("Location for \"Coordinates\" is [\(location?.coordinate.latitude), \(String(describing: location?.coordinate.longitude))]")
        } else {
            print("GeoFire does not contain a location for \"Coordinates\"")
        }
    }

    let query1 = geoFire.query(at: self.dict, withRadius: 3)
    query1.observe(.keyEntered, with: { key, location in
        print("Key: " + key + "entered the search radius.") ///**this prints keys of users within 3 miles. This is where I see the wrong inclusions or exclusions**
        do {
            self.componentArray.append(key)
        }
            print(self.componentArray,"kr")
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough code to go on to provide an answer. For example, what is `self.dict` and when is it updated? What is the first section of code related to the second section? Do they run at different times or sequentially as shown?

Comment: @Jay my bad. `dict` is set in the specialized didUpdateLocations function. I have added it to the question. Those sections run underneath each other in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: When adding code to your question, please ensure it's formatted nicely using the formatting tools. When it's all crazy-pants formatted, it's unreadable and many users will just skip over the question. I formatted for you.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code in the question so the issue lies outside that code. Perhaps you are not removing them from the array using .keyExited so they then exist twice?

Comment: Thank you. I usually do Control I for formatting, but will pay more attention to that in furture

Comment: @Jay RE the second comment. I am not removing anything with .keyExited. Should I? Before coding this, I read the documentation on geoqueries (https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/geofire-objc/) and saw .keyExited. The way I understood it was that you choose one of the 3 key options (these and keyMoved). I replaced keyEntered with keyExited just to see how it works yesterday. KeyExited as expected put the user in the array if he exited the range, but since I am interested in the ones in the range, I only used KeyEntered.

Comment: @Jay With the help of prints, I better understand the mechanism of action of the problem, so to speak. Say a user wasn't in the array the previous launch. Now if you launch, all other users who were there previously get called via key entered, then what I want to do with the array gets done, then the news user who is in the radius prints with "entered the search radius." This all happens in viewdidLoad, but it makes little sense that all the "entered the search radius" (which would include the new one) don't get printed together before the rest of ViewDidLoad.

Comment: When the app starts, a .keyEntered event fires, and all of the keys that match the query criteria will be returned. This allows the dataSource to be initially populated. When a key leaves the radius, that event is fired and the key should be removed from the dataSource as it no longer matches the query criteria. Likewise, if a new key enters the radius they should be added to the dataSource. .keyExisted events always match to .keyEntered event. Not removing them creates dups in the dataSource. See the docs [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#receiving-events-for-geo-queries)

Comment: RE the first half of your comment: That makes sense. However, what doesn't make sense is if someone exits the radius before the app is started again. When the app is then launched the one who exited while the app was offline shouldn't be part of keyEntered. Am I right? That is what I am seeing right now. I added an array for .KeyExited and filtered the .KeyEntered array to exclude the .KeyExited array, yet I still observe this.

Comment: If the app is started and there are 4 keys in the radius, keyEntered will return 4 results. Then the app is quit and one user leaves the radius. When the app is started again, (which calls keyEntered) it will now have 3 keys. Do you have persistence enabled?

Comment: That is exactly how I want it to act, but it does not. I don't think it is enabled. In didFinishLaunching/App Delegate I only have FirebaseApp.configure()

Comment: I'm not sure how to call the location in view did load, but I'll look into this. Location Manager is call in ViewDidLoad too. I'll try it, but would be stunned if it makes a difference. Why do you think it would? self.dict always printed out successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do for testing and maybe a solution. This is similar to your code but takes some of the unknowns out of the equation; I think we maybe running into an asynchronous issue as well, so give this a try.

In viewDidLoad get the current users position. That position will be used as the center point of the query

```
self.geoFire.getLocationForKey(uid) { (location, error) in
    if (error != nil) {
        print("An error occurred getting the location for \"Coordinates\": \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

    } else if (location != nil) {
        self.setupCircleQueryWith(center: location) //pass the known location

    } else {
        print("GeoFire does not contain a location for \"Coordinates\"")
    }
}
```

Once the `location` var is populated within the closure (so you know it's valid) pass it to a function to generate the query

```
func setupCircleQueryWith(center: CLLLocation) {
    var circleQuery = self.geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 3.0)

    self.queryHandle = self.circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { key, location in
      print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
      self.myKeyArray.append(key)
    })
}
```

`self.queryHandle` is a class var we can use to remove the query at a later time. I also set up `self.geoFire` as a class var that points to `Loc`.

**EDIT**

At the very top of your class, add a class var to store the keys

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var myKeyArray = [String]()
    let queryHandle: DatabaseHandle!
```

and remember to also add a .keyExited event so you will know when to remove a key from the array when the key exits the area.

Comment: Thanks. I think it has potential. Just an issue. I would have to append with the keys inside the query. Since I have to use the appended array downstream in ViewDidLoad, I will have to find a way to "unlock" it from the closure. Also just Fyi observeEventType has changed to .observe and .queryAtLocation to .query. Swift forces me to change to those.

Comment: RE Async issue. It is indeed an issue. How I know this: if you print out the appended array, sometimes a new element (user in radius) prints out after the rest of viewDidLoad. From what I read in docs, query.observeReady{/rest of ViewDidLoad} is supposed to prevent that, but it doesn't.

Comment: @florida27 That was a copy and paste from the geoFire site so yes, `.observe(` is correct at this time. *I would have to append with the keys inside the query* is correct -  that's how you build your array, which would be a class var. It would not be tied to the closure in any way so I am not sure what you mean by `unlock`. I added an EDIT to the answer for additional clarification and added a `self.myKeyArray.append(key)` to append the key to that array.

Comment: @ Jay By unlock I just mean use the array outside the closure. That is not possible for me even when it is defined at class level like your edit. I can however include the code where the array is used in the last } of `self.geoFire.getLocationForKey(uid)`, then it can be used.  How would you remove from the array with .keyExited? Last week I made another array for the exits and made the Entered Array exclude those (if I recall correctly), but I am thinking there should be a way to directly remove from this array with . Exited.

Comment: Also, is this how you'd define the variables:     `var queryHandle: DatabaseHandle?`
    `var geoFire = GeoFire( firebaseRef: Database.database().reference().child("Loc"))`
    `var circleQuery: GFCircleQuery?`

Comment: *That is not possible* - how is it not possible? It's fundamental coding that's used in pretty much every app? I would suggest investigating why it's not possible as that is part of the issue. Remove they key from the array by finding the key that's exited (the ones that passed to the closure) in the array and removing it..? Your last comment; you only need a class var queryHandle so you can remove the observe. I don't understand the purpose of the rest of the code. See [Firebase handles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data) `let queryHandle: DatabaseHandle!`